# Comparing mixed effect models fitted to two different datasets

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have two different time series data which are the results of running a simulation model with different sets of parameters and configurations. The datasets each contain 100 time series which indicate the evolution of the target outcome (LGRD) through the simulation steps (Days). There are 70 entry points for each time series, which vary between -0.1 to about 1. Here's an example of one of these time series:

[image]

My objective is to compare the trends in these two datasets in more detail than just at the aggregated level. For example, I want to know whether one contains more negative trends or if the correlation between intercepts and slopes varies across models...

I thought using mixed effect models could help me address such an objective and therefore, I fitted two random slope models to each of these datasets (using the lmer package in R: LGRD ~ Day + (1 + Day|Subject). I can tell from plotting the random effects for each model that one shows more negative trends than the other and overall has more flat trends. Here are the plotted random slopes of the two mixed-effect models:

[image] [image]

However, I want to draw these conclusions quantitatively...

Is there a valid way to compare the outcomes of two mixed-effect models fitted to two different datasets? I can think of some methods but as I am not an expert in statistics I'm not sure if I could trust my thoughts on this matter ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Combine the datasets and fit a model `LGRD ~ Day * dataset + (1 + Day|Subject)`.

Comment: If you go down this approach of using a single model, you may also want to allow the within-group residuals to vary across dataset. You would need to move over to `nlme()` for that. Probably using the `varIdent(form=~1|dataset)` specification.

Comment: @ErikRuzek Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the concept you mentioned. I tried to do as Roland suggested and had difficulty interpreting the results. For example, in the combined version there were no negative slopes, only that the dataset and the interaction between the dataset and Day had negative fixed effect estimations.